# Is it possible to integrate Javascript IDE into Eclipse PDT?

Tags: php, javascript, eclipse, ide

I currently have Eclipse PDT for PHP, I can use HTML,CSS Javascript, PHP as normal but my eclipse dosent have error code checking for Javascript. What can I download into my eclipse so I can see any Javascript errors in my Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you go try [Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/) for HTML, CSS and JS. And since it's an eclipse based IDE, you can download and install PDT on it for your PHP.

Comment: Note that aptana studio can be installed as a plugin in vanilla eclipse. Also, the standalone version support PHP out of the box.